# Generate an integer of a certain length (byte size is fine too)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've figure out a way to do this but it doesn't seem as efficient/clean as it could be to me.  I need a function to return an integer the size of .  For instance, `generate_int(4)` should generate an integer that is 4 characters long.

My current logic creates a string representation of the integer and then converts it like below:

```
def _gen_int(num):
    string = ''.join(str(random.randint(0,9)) for i in range(num))
    int(string)
```

I imagine there is a better way that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: `random.randint(10**(num-1), 10**num-1)`

Comment: The *string* `0001‘ is 4 bytes long. But is it a 4-byte integer?

Comment: @usr2564301 that was a question I actually had.  If I do `sys.getsizeof()`, I get much larger results than 4 for both cases.

Comment: On the string or on the integer? As you see they  may be different – and which value to use is up to you to decide.

Comment: @SamDillard integer of length 4 and bit representation of length 4 are different things, which one do you need?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'd like "length in bytes".  That's a thing, right?

Comment: @SamDillard can you give an example?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'm just wondering how to interpret the byte size of objects.  If I `sys.getsizeof(5)`, I get `28`.  However, UTF-8 encoded, it's `1` byte.  I'm just not sure what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use powers of ten as limits to the `random.randint` function:

```
def _gen_int(num):
    return random.randint(10 ** (num - 1), 10 ** num - 1)
```

For `num = 4`, `10 ** (num - 1)` is `1000` (lower limit) and `10 ** num - 1` is `9999` (higher limit).

Answer (score 1):

A simple, fast way would be

```py
from math import pow
from random import randint

num = 7
low = pow(10, num-1)
high = pow(10, num)-1
print(randint(low, high))
```